# Strange behavior after setting WPF window as a child window of Shell_TrayWnd

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi

I have encountered a strange phenomenon when setting a WPF window as a child window of Shell_TrayWnd. Instead of displaying the content of my window, it seems to be rendering the content of the taskbar itself, as shown in the image.
[image: glitch]

Here is the code I am using to insert the WPF window, which overlaps the taskbar window of TrafficMonitor:

```cs
// Executed in the Loaded event of the Window
windowInteropHelper = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
thisHandle = windowInteropHelper.Handle;

// Get the window on the taskbar
shellTray = PInvoke.User32.FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", null);
notify = PInvoke.User32.FindWindowEx(shellTray, IntPtr.Zero, "TrayNotifyWnd", null);

// Get the window rectangles
PInvoke.User32.GetWindowRect(thisHandle, out PInvoke.RECT thisRect);
PInvoke.User32.GetWindowRect(notify, out PInvoke.RECT notifyRect);

// Set Shell_TrayWnd as my window's parent and set the window position
PInvoke.User32.SetParent(thisHandle, shellTray);
PInvoke.User32.MoveWindow(thisHandle, notifyRect.left - thisRect.Width(), 25, thisRect.Width(), thisRect.Height(), true);
```

Initially, I thought this issue was specific to WPF, but when I tried using a WinForms window with the same approach, I encountered the same problem.

Could anyone provide insights into why this behavior occurs and suggest possible solutions?

Comment: You can't just inject your random window from a different process into the parent child hierarchy of another window. The solution is to stop doing that.

Comment: But I can do this before. It doesn't work after a system update.

Comment: There's a distinct difference between code that works by virtue of being correct, and code that appears to work because it hasn't failed yet. Your code falls into the second category (see [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683)).